# entire textbox isn't highlighted in asp.net mvc form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

[Login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfSR8.png)

This is the code for the login form. From the picture it can be seen that the entire textbox isn't highlighted. What am I missing?

```
    <div class="login">

        <div class="login-form">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <h2 style="margin-left:-15px">Login</h2>
                <div id="maintenance"></div>
                <div class="bg-danger text-danger FailureCont">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span id="BodyContent_LoginCtrl_UserNameRequired" title="Username is required." class="bg-danger text-danger block" style="visibility:hidden">Username is required.</span>

                    <div class="input-group login-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>

                        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email", aria_required = true })</div>


                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                        @*    <input name="ctl00$BodyContent$LoginCtrl$UserName" type="text" id="BodyContent_LoginCtrl_UserName" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" data-validate="placeholder required" />*@


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span id="BodyContent_LoginCtrl_PasswordRequired" title="Password is required." class="bg-danger text-danger block" style="visibility:hidden;">Password is required.</span>
                    <div class="input-group login-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </span>
                        @*<input name="ctl00$BodyContent$LoginCtrl$Password" type="password" id="BodyContent_LoginCtrl_Password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled" data-validate="placeholder required" />*@

                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 small-side-padding">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" id="" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Register","Account")'">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 small-side-padding">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="bSummit" value="Login" />
                        @*<input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$LoginCtrl$LoadingLoginButton" value="Login" id="BodyContent_LoginCtrl_LoadingLoginButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden"/>*@
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*<input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyContent$LoginCtrl$LoginButton" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />*@


                <div class="form-group text-center forgottenCont">
                    Need help with your <a class="forgottenpwd" href="/Account/ForgotPassword.cshtml">username</a> or <a class="forgottenpwd" href="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account")">password</a>?
                </div>




            }


        </div>
        <div class="text-center login-icons hidden-ph">
            <a href="http://twitter.com" target="new"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" target="new"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="new"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a>


        </div>

    </div>
```

I'm not sure why the entire textbox isn't highlighted. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like some CSS is overriding your input field, if you dont mind can you share your CSS for .login-group

Answer (score 0):

```
           .login-group {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.login-group .form-control {
border: 0;}
```

@Nimmi: Not sure if any style is overridden here, but thanks :)